# Count within the result set of a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following relations in my database:

```
Invoice                           InvoiceMeal
---------------------             ---------------------------
| InvoiceId | Total |             | Id | InvoiceId | MealId |
---------------------             ---------------------------
| 1         | 22.32 |             | 1  | 1         | 3      |
---------------------             ---------------------------
| 2         | 12.18 |             | 2  | 1         | 2      |
---------------------             ---------------------------
| 3         | 27.76 |             | 3  | 2         | 2      |
---------------------             ---------------------------

Meal                                            Type
-----------------------------------             -------------------
| Id     | Name          | TypeId |             | Id | Name       |
-----------------------------------             -------------------
| 1      | Hamburger     | 1      |             | 1  | Meat       |
-----------------------------------             -------------------
| 2      | Soja Beans    | 2      |             | 2  | Vegetarian |
-----------------------------------             -------------------
| 3      | Chicken       | 2      |
-----------------------------------
```

What I want to query from the database is `InvoiceId` and `Total` of all `Invoices` which consist of at least two `Meals` where at least one of the `Meals` is of `Type` *Vegetarian*. I have the following SQL query and it works:

```
SELECT 
   i."Id", i."Total"
FROM 
   public."Invoice" i
WHERE
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM public."InvoiceMeal" im
   WHERE im."InvoiceId" = i."Id" AND
                              (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                              FROM public."Meal" m, public."Type" t
                              WHERE im."MealId" = m."Id" AND
                              m."TypeId" = t."Id" AND 
                              g."Name" = 'Vegetarian') > 0
   ) >= 2;
```

My problem with this query is that I can not easily modify the condition that there must at least one vegetarien `Meal`. I want to be able, for example, to change it to at least two vegetarian meals. How can I achieve this with my query?

Comment: What SQL system?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  MySQL?

Comment: It's Postgresql, but the query should use plain SQL only. So no vendor-specific constructs for portability.

Comment: Just so you know, "portable" isn't just about avoiding "vendor-specific constructs"; some well-standardised features are simply missing from some products, and others have subtle variations to watch out for. It's a worthy goal, though, and probably achievable in this case at a cost of convenient shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this by joining the tables together and using aggregation.  The `having` clause can handle the conditions:

```
select i.Id, i.Total
from InvoiceMeal im join
     Invoice i
     on i.InvoiceId = im.InvoiceId join
     Meal m
     on im.mealid = m.mealid join
     Type t
     on m.typeid = t.typeid
group by i.Id, i.Total
having count(distinct im.mealid) >= 2 and
       sum(case when t.name = 'Vegetarian' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

I also see no reason to put double quotes around column names.  That just makes the query harder to write and read.

Comment: Isn't it possible to keep the sub queries somehow?

Comment: The double-quotes are necessary if the table names contain uppercase letters, because in Postgres `InvoiceMeal` folds to `invoicemeal` but `"InvoiceMeal"` does not. However, that conflicts with the OP's aim of keeping the query portable to other DBMSes, where the quoting (and case-folding) is different.

Comment: @Djihad Why do you want sub-queries, if you can avoid them? This solution is much easier to read and manipulate, and easier for the DBMS to optimise. If the invoice had a series of line prices that needed summing, you would need two separate aggregations, so a sub-query of some sort would probably be unavoidable, but in this case you have a single column which can appear in the `GROUP BY` and be unaffected by the extra rows introduced in the `JOIN` clauses.